# CSS The text moves horizontally when scrolling vertically in Android device

Tags: android, css, scroll

I'm working on a website that contains text content (loaded with xml) within other divs.
The problem I encounter is that when the text is very extensive and I scroll vertically, the text also moves horizontally (though overflow-x: hidden) like vibrate.

This only happens when I check it on an Android device in the pc / mac works properly in all browsers.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` property for the text inner container and `position:relative` for the outer container